# control loop lose its desired rate

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

###Hi,every earnest fork##
In the past of couples weeks, I have been tuning robot's navigation. But it still have some troubles when going to nav goals even with a static map.

One of those question is control loop always lose its desire rate. When I use my own notebook on the robot, I set control frequency = 8Hz, and it runs good, but when I use another computer, the warning always jump onto screen. I know the reason is either the latter computer sucked or some parameter was not properly set.

Here it is the key configuration about the latter computer

> Intel Atom D2550 1.86GHz

> 2G RAM

and base_local_planner parameter

```
controller_frequency: 8
recovery_behavior_enabled: true
clearing_rotation_allowed: true

TrajectoryPlannerROS:
   max_vel_x: 0.55
   min_vel_x: 0.25
   max_vel_theta: 1.2
   min_vel_theta: -1.2
   min_in_place_vel_theta: 0.9
   escape_vel: -0.4
   acc_lim_x: 2.0
   acc_lim_y: 2.0
   acc_lim_theta: 2.5

   holonomic_robot: false
   yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.3 # about 18 degrees
   xy_goal_tolerance: 0.2  # 10 cm
   latch_xy_goal_tolerance: true
   pdist_scale: 0.8
   gdist_scale: 0.4
   meter_scoring: true

   heading_lookahead: 0.5
   heading_scoring: true
   heading_scoring_timestep: 0.8
   occdist_scale: 0.3
   oscillation_reset_dist: 0.1
   publish_cost_grid_pc: true
   prune_plan: true

   sim_time: 2.0
   sim_granularity: 0.04
   angular_sim_granularity: 0.025
   vx_samples: 18
   vtheta_samples: 30
   dwa: true
   simple_attractor: false
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/152376/control-loop-lose-its-desired-rate/) by [zsbhaha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13451/zsbhaha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Those messages are related to your computer not being able to complete all the calculations in the frequency you asked. So if you have those warnings in one machine but not in the other, that means the culprit is the lack of power on your computer.
You can relax some of the parameters if you want to keep the 8hz frequency, specially the last block in your config file. For instance, try to reduce the **sim_time**, **vx_samples** and **vtheta_samples** and increase **sim_granularity** and **angular_sim_granularity**.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2014-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zsbhaha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13451/zsbhaha/) on 2014-04-14**:
Thanks for your suggestion .